# Free plugins for making drones and textures?

Tags: plug-ins, logic, drone, texture

I want to be able to process audio files or synths to create new drones and textures in Logic Express 9. Anyone has any suggestions of which free plugins are worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

Paulstretch is great for creating long, evolving textures and drones out of anything. Guitar riffs work incredibly well if you want a place to start.

Logic also has a convolution plugin called Space Designer, great for convolving two sounds together.
An interesting combination you can try out is having the sound of fire crackling be your source audio and a synth pad as the AUX sound. Process with some delays and reverbs for added warmth.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Norris' Soundmagic plugin suite has an FFT dronemaker included.  I've gotten some pretty good stuff out of it.